# Python in Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows-8.1

Attempting to run a .py file in PS, but nothing happens. Have installed Anaconda 3 for python - this set up yielded no problems in W7, unfortunately W7 is getting in the way of time so I had to upgrade, but this OS is seriously the biggest pain in the royal fleet.

[image]

Comment: You'll get a better response here if you paste your error messages as **text**; screenshots, especially those without accompanying text, are generally discouraged on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I said in the beginning of the post that nothing happens - there is no error message. I demonstrated the execution, after which Nothing happens via the screenshot and it is very  concise for that purpose.
I am asking for help, because I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Python seems to be working fine. What is the script supposed to do? Maybe you forgot to pass in parameters? Did you write the script or somebody else? Did you try running it with `python taring.py`?

Comment: @AlvinLepik: I was referring to the messages printed by PowerShell